# API Ключи твиттера

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-api

Ребят пишу твитер бота на c#. В нем я использую пару ключей:

```
ConsumerKey = "****",
ConsumerSecret = "*****",
```

которые я сгенерил в своем приложении, еще одну пару ключей я выдергиваю у каждого аккаунта, с которым работает приложение:

```
AccessToken = row["oauthToken"].ToString(),
AccessTokenSecret = row["oauthTokenSecret"].ToString()
```

Вопрос в следующем:

нормально ли использовать всем пользователям моей программы мою пару ключей Consumer? Не заблокирует ли всех их твиттер.

Или пусть генерят себе каждый сам ключи, как это сделали в твидиуме?